# Nodemon - ignore everything except repeated specific sub directories

Tags: match, glob, nodemon

How to make `nodemon` ignore everything in a folder, except nested sub directories?
I want to ignore everything in `src` folder except every folder with name `components` (nested etc.)

so `src/file.js`, `src/something/nested/file.js` should be ignored, but `src/components/file.js`, `src/something/nested/components/file.js` should not be ignored.

I tried `!` but it doesn't work.

```
{
    "verbose": true,
    "ignore": [
        "vite.config.js.timestamp-*.mjs",
        "node_modules/",
        "src/!(**/components/**)",
        "dist/"
    ],
    "ext": "*"
}
```